# How to manage more than 1 resources?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

I have model for my MVC-page. I want to use a resource of a determined language. I want a dynamic solution in my DataAnnotations.

How do you do that?

[image: ambiguous refrerence]

Comment: How are you adding a new resource file? You can follow the steps mentioned in [this](http://www.codedigest.com/posts/29/using-resource-file-for-dataannotations-display-attribute-with-multi-language-support-in-aspnet-mvc) article to add a new language resource file.

Comment: Thank you. I have read your link and I have used this solution. And it works fine.